# Django many-to-many multiple filtering

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have a model that is as follows:

```py
class NetworkDevice(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class NetworkInterface(models.Model):
    intname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    device = models.ForeignKey(NetworkDevice)

class NetworkMac(models.Model):
    macaddr = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    interface = models.ManyToManyField(NetworkInterface)
```

I want to create a device detail page that shows only the MACs learned off the interfaces assigned to that particular device. The issue is that the same mac address lives off different interfaces on different devices. if I pass my template something like:

```py
macs = NetworkMac.objects.filter(interface__device__name='<some device name>')
```

Doing this gives me all the MAC addresses for that device, but because the MACs are shared, it also gives me the MACs associated with interfaces on other devices. So when I try to display this in my template, it ends giving me nothing or if I use `|first`, it will often give me the interface for a different device depending on the order the devices were added to the database.

What I really need is a query I can run that will return all the macs for a single device only learned on the interfaces that are associated with said device.

**Update:**
Just to give a bit more detail. The way i'm getting around this now is to define a method in my view like so...

```
class DeviceDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'NetViewer/Device_detail_template.html'
    model = NetworkDevice

    def mac_ip_table(self, device_pk):
        ints = NetworkInterface.objects.filter(hostdevice__hostname=device_pk.hostname)
        mac_list = []
        for int in ints:
            for mac in int.networkmacs.all():
                ip_qs = NetworkIP.objects.filter(mac__macaddr=mac.macaddr)
                ip_list = [ip.ip for ip in ip_qs]
                mac_list.append(tuple([mac.macaddr, ip_list, int.intname]))
        return mac_list

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        device = NetworkDevice.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        args = {'macs': self.mac_ip_table(device), 'device': device}

        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Then I loop through what `mac_ip_table` returns in my template. The downside to this is that it's really inefficient and would probably make pagination impossible.

When I jump through multiple models, such as...

`macs = NetworkMac.objects.filter(interface__hostdevice__hostname=device_pk.hostname)`

I need a way to filter this query only for interfaces that are associated with the device. I'm relatively new to Django, so don't hurt me if this question is completely off base or if I'm missing something completely

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem.  Can you provide sample data, along with your desired results?

Comment: The query ```macs = NetworkMac.objects.filter(interface__device__name='<some device name>')``` returns a query-set of macs for that device, but some of those same macs are linked to other devices in addition the device i'm filtering on (because of the many-to-many). i want to run a query that filters on the device name and only the interfaces linked back to that device. i hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

This should be useful:

```
 macs = NetworkMac.objects.filter(interface__exact='<some device name>')
```